# PHP to Python conversion to get timezone offset

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, timezone, timezone-offset

I am new to Python and would like to do the same thing below in Python instead of PHP.

```
$timestamp = 1414231200;
$timezone = 'Australia/NSW';
$offset = timezone_offset_get(timezone_open($timezone), new DateTime()); //39600 (11 Hours)
$adjust = $timestamp + $offset;
$new = new DateTime('@'.$adjust);
print_r($new->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'));
```

Result: 2014-10-25T21:00:00

I am using GAE (Google App Engine) and it looks like I can't import pytz. Are there any other solutions?

I have tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

TIMESTAMP = 1415700000;
TIMEZONE = timezone('Australia/NSW')
FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%M:%S'
#Not sure how to get offset

NEW = TIMEZONE.localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(TIMESTAMP))
NEW.strftime(FORMAT)
print(NEW)
```

But get the error: **ImportError: No module named pytz**

Comment: Can you show us what have you tired in python.

Comment: Added what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use this and achieve this: https://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/
I think you might also be able to use pytz, but you'll have to manually install it: [How to properly add PyTZ to a Google App Engine application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718724/how-to-properly-add-pytz-to-a-google-app-engine-application)

Comment: Thank you, gae-pytz sounds like what I need. I can't find any information for installing it however. Have you come across any guides? I have the files do I just add them to the root directory?

Comment: Download the source from the link and then the pytz directory to the root of your app engine project.